# jenkins plugin installation failed with error certification expired

Tags: jenkins, ssl-certificate, certificate, client-certificates, x509certificate2

Jenkins plugins installation failed with below error

```
ERROR: cannot verify pkg.jenkins.io 1’s certificate, issued by ‘/C=US/O=Let’s Encrypt/CN=R3’: Issued certificate has expired.
```

Access to any sub domain of jenkins.io also gives certificate error

```
wget https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.303.3/jenkins.war
--2023-05-10 19:47:32--  https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.303.3/jenkins.war
Connecting to 10.65.1.6:8080... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify get.jenkins.io's certificate, issued by '/C=US/O=Let\'s Encrypt/CN=R3':
 ** Issued certificate has expired**.
To connect to get.jenkins.io insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

It should install plugin or download war from jenkins.io without certification issue

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me

`sudo yum install -y ca-certificates`

If you download manually, you could use the “--no-check-certificate” option to download insecurely.